# Gulp download remote JSON files during build

Tags: gulp

I have a static site reliant on a remote JSON file which is under my control and doesn't change much.

I'm using gulp to build the static site and would like to add a gulp task to automatically get the remote JSON during the build, so I can include it as a local file.

I've not come across a plug-in to do this. Can anybody suggest one?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-download-files will allow you to download files locally.